# Flask - python header import is not working

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Server - Flask + Python 2.6.2 + CentOS

**Dashboard**

```
@app.route('/admin/dashboard')
def admin_dashboard():
    return render_template('admin/dashboard.html')
```

I tried to load dashboard.html with header.thml

**dashboard.html**

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
<div>
    dashboard
</div>
```

After this I get this error.

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
TemplateNotFound: header.html
```

I tried other methods, and it didn't work..

Can you see what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/,  your templates need to be in a folder named "templates". Header.html should be in [project]/templates/header.html.

Comment: Thanks!! I put my file template/admin/header.html like this. I changed it {% include 'admin/header.html' %} and it worked! Thank you.